# Python requests.post doesn't post (with cloudfare bypass)

Tags: python, python-requests

I created a skript that will create and account on:
https://stress95.com/en/auth/view?op=register

```
import requests
import cloudscraper
import time


url = ('https://stress95.com/en/auth/view?op=register')

headers = {

    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
}


payload = {'firstName': 'test', 'email': 'afaff@pytronik.club', 'password': '12341fbb14', 'action': 'register', '_AntiCsrfToken': '3dee97c161c84c13a4400d19a8c6565c'}

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(interpreter='nodejs')  # returns a CloudScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
#print(scraper.get(url).text)

r = scraper.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Please help me out I'm getting crazy about this

Comment: Hello Pytronik, what code later fixed the issue for you?

Comment: I had to rewrite the whole code and I implemented 2captcha, also I'm now scraping the token.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am having the same issue with sneakersnstuff website. looks like their registration forms are the same.  I already posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103686/cloudscrape-request-post-giving-500-status . I also added 2captcha but still getting error.

Comment: I hope to get an answer from you. Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you dm me on Discoord? Makes it easier : pytronik#0001 thank you

Comment: okay. I will now

Comment: Hello, your discoord handle is not working.

Comment: I can't seem to connect with you. please try adding me- Steph#8620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are posting to the *wrong place*.  The url you linked is the endpoint that has a registration form.  That registration form posts over here:

```
<form action="/en/auth/submit" method="post" class="login-form">
...
</form>
```

It's also worth nothing that just posting to their page isn't likely to *do much* because the first element in their form as an anti-csrf token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_AntiCsrfToken" value="149d3fbcfdf74aec9eed68a4b78d33bf">
```

Your post won't have that value unless you loaded it from the page, which means they'll just reject your request.